# Pass arguments to the class constructor after import

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Here is my **parent.class.js**

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor() {
    }
}

module.exports = { ParentClass };
```

**child.class.js**

```
const { ParentClass } = require('./parent.class');

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor(index) {
        super();
        this.index = index;
    }

    showIndex() {
        console.log(this.index)
    }
}

module.exports = { ChildClass };
```

And **index.js** where I'm using the child class

```
const ChildClass = require('./child.class');

ChildClass(1).showIndex(); // This obviously is not working
```

*NOTE: this is only an example. In the actual project I'm not able to use ES6 module import*

My question is how can I pass parameters to child class instance in my **index.js**?

In case of ES6 I would be able to do something like this:

```
import ChildClass  from './child.class.js'

const ChildClass = new ChildClass(1)

ChildClass.showIndex(); // outputs 1 ...I guess??
```

How do I pass argument to the childclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
module.exports = { ChildClass };
```

and

```
const ChildClass = require('./child.class');
```

You're exporting an *object* which has a property of `ChildClass` there, and then you're importing the *whole object* and trying to call it. But objects aren't callable; you aren't referring to the `ChildClass` class.

Just like you destructured the `ParentClass` with

```
const { ParentClass } = require('./parent.class');
```

Either destructure the `ChildClass`:

```
const { ChildClass } = require('./child.class');
```

Or assign the `ChildClass` to the `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = ChildClass;
```

And then you'll be able to create instances of the `ChildClass` and call methods on the instance:

```
const child = new ChildClass(1);
child.showIndex();
```